# I do not see all builds from TestFlight in Xcode Organizer, why?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, beta

When I go to Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> Crashes, to debug my application, I can only see a few builds (7) but when I open TestFlight physically on device there are 17 previous build configurations and the current version = 18 total.

My collegues see more builds in the Organizer than me, I have run out of ideas. Do you have any, please? Ever happened to anyone?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @matt Hi, I am not talking about archives. When I go to the `Crashes` tab in Organizer You can choose the build version to see the crashes on: `App Store` -> `Build XXX` but the problem is that when I expand the list of builds by clicking on `AppStore` I see less builds than my collegues.

Comment: Hmmm, report that as a bug to Apple?

Comment: Yeah I will probably do that and maybe someone from the Apple community will be able to help. Thanks!